# Why can i not place my towers down (roblox)

Tags: lua, roblox

Im making a tower defense game and i was modifying my script to make it so that when u place a tower down u have to press the button again to place another one down then i started working on a valid and invalid placement areas. once i finished it i tested it and got an error with one of my then and end statements. I played around with it until the red lines indicating errors disappeared but then when i tested it the button stopped working but i didnt get any error messages. I turned the script back how it used to be with the red lines under my ends and now i dont know what to do. Here is the script, the part im having trouble with is the part at the bottom. this is the error message im getting " Players.ASWXDYC2.PlayerGui.ScreenGui.GameController:143: Expected 'end' (to close 'function' at line 48), got ; did you forget to close 'then' at line 85? "

here is the script.

````
local RunService = game:GetService("RunService")
local UserInputService = game:GetService("UserInputService")
local camera = workspace.CurrentCamera
local towerToSpawn = nil
local gui = script.Parent
local replicatedstorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local towers = replicatedstorage:WaitForChild("Towers")
local PhysicsService = game:GetService("PhysicsService")
local events = replicatedstorage:WaitForChild("Events")
local spawnTowerEvent = events:WaitForChild("SpawnTower")
local canPlace = false


local function MouseRaycast(blacklist)
    
    local mousePosition = UserInputService:GetMouseLocation()

    local mouseRay = camera:ViewportPointToRay(mousePosition.X,mousePosition.Y)
    local raycastParams = RaycastParams.new()
    
    raycastParams.FilterType = Enum.RaycastFilterType.Blacklist
    raycastParams.FilterDescendantsInstances = blacklist
    
    
    local raycastResult = workspace:Raycast(mouseRay.Origin, mouseRay.Direction * 1000, raycastParams)

    return raycastResult
end

local function RemovePlaceholderTower()
    if towerToSpawn then
        towerToSpawn:Destroy()
        towerToSpawn = nil
    end
end

local function AddPlaceHolderTower(name)
    
    local towerExists = towers:FindFirstChild(name)
    if towerExists then
        RemovePlaceholderTower()
        towerToSpawn = towerExists:Clone()
        towerToSpawn.Parent = workspace.Towers

    end
end

local function ColorPlaceholderTower(color)

    for i, object in ipairs(towerToSpawn:GetDescendants()) do
        if object:IsA("BasePart") then
            object.Color = color
        end
end

gui.Gunslinger.Activated:Connect(function()
    AddPlaceHolderTower("Gunslinger")
    
end)

UserInputService.InputBegan:Connect(function(input, processed)
    if processed then
        return
    end
    
    if towerToSpawn then
        if input.UserInputType == Enum.UserInputType.MouseButton1 then
                if canPlace then
                    spawnTowerEvent:FireServer(towerToSpawn.Name, towerToSpawn.PrimaryPart.CFrame)
                    RemovePlaceholderTower()
                end
                

                
        end
    end
    
end)



RunService.RenderStepped:Connect(function()
    if towerToSpawn then
    local result = MouseRaycast({towerToSpawn})
        if result and result.Instance then
            if result.Instance.Parent.Name == "TowerArea" then
            canPlace = true
            ColorPlaceholderTower(Color3.new(0,1,0))
        else
            canPlace = false
            ColorPlaceholderTower(Color3.new(1,0,0))
        end
        local x = result.Position.X
        local y = result.Position.Y + towerToSpawn.Humanoid.HipHeight + (towerToSpawn.PrimaryPart.Size.Y * 2)
        local z = result.Position.Z
        
        local cframe = CFrame.new(x,y,z)
        towerToSpawn:SetPrimaryPartCFrame(cframe)
            
        end
    end
end)```
````

Comment: Your error message is suggesting a fix. Reread the suggestion and then take a look at your `ColorPlaceholderTower` function.

Answer (score 1):

So basically the problem wasnt that i didnt have enough "ends" in my renderstepped part. I had to add another end in my ColorPlaceHolderTower function.